# how can i reload the site again and again from aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a internal site called DataEntry.com which is made in such a way that whenever we load the page it will save some data into the database. but my requirement is that i have to load the page programatically from aspx page. i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   window.location.replace("http://DataEntry.com");
});
```

but once it is redirected I cant load again. and the Dataentry.com is not editable because it is in exe form.. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This really is strange requirement. Use `setinterval` to call function after specific interval

Use setinterval

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function() {
    //ur code
}, 1000);//1000 is in miliseconds=1 second 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a window.refresh method in javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

It can also take in a parameter that does a hard refresh (ignoring the cached version)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    location.reload(true);
});
```

That being said, this is a very strange requirement. What are you trying to accomplish?